# How to parse HTML with nested tags using Simple DOM Parser?

Tags: php, html, parsing, dom

I have a HTML file that I'm trying to parse. It has a bunch of DIVs like this:

```
<div class="doc-overview">
<h2>Description</h2>
<div id="doc-description-container" class="" style="max-height: 605px;">
<div class="doc-description toggle-overflow-contents" data-collapsed-height="200">
<div id="doc-original-text">
Content of the div without paragraph tags.
<p>Content from the first paragraph </p>
<p>Content from the second paragraph</p>
<p>Content from the third paragraph</p>

</div>
</div>
<div class="doc-description-overflow"></div>
</div>
```

I tried this:

```
foreach($html->find('div[id=doc-original-text]') as $div) {         
                echo $div->innertext;
            }
```

You notice that I directly find the `doc-original-text` but I also tried to parse from outer divs to inner divs.

Comment: Can you add the info like how do you want the output to be displayed? Just a sample?

Comment: i didn't understand, what are you wanting to get ? and what are you getting for the moment ?

Comment: just want to get all content within doc-original-text div...

Comment: The `id` attibute should be unique in the HTML document. Therefore the `for` loop does not make any sense.

Comment: for the given input , your test code works fine. Provide more information like errors you got or full html code you are trying to parse

Comment: @EdHeal : I can have more `div` with same class attribute , so `for` loop is needed in that case to iterate thru those elements.

Comment: Then `'div[id=doc-original-text]'` should read `'div[class=doc-original-text]'` and the appropriate changes made in the HTML. As it standands you are using the `id` attibute when you should be using the class attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Try This,

```
foreach($html->find('div#doc-original-text') as $div) {         
            echo $div->innertext;
        }
```